# How can I estimate THREE parameters in R using nls

Tags: r, parameters, statistics, nls

I have fitted a model and estimated parameters for;

```
Count = beta0*exp(beta1*time)
```

If an additional parameter is introduced such that the model becomes;

```
Count = alpha + (beta)*exp(beta1*time)
```

I tried using the same method as i did to find just the `beta0` and `beta1` term using the command;

```
fit<-nls(count~beta*exp(beta1*time), start=list(alpha=0, beta0=500, bet1=0), data=radiation)
```

but get the following error...

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With your starting value of `beta1=0`, your equation `alpha+beta0*exp(beta1*time)` reduces to `alpha+beta0`, which means that the derivatives of the function with respect to `alpha` and `beta0` are confounded.  Try changing your starting value for `beta1` to something slightly different from 0 ...

Comment: I tried using a value of 0.1, 0.5 and 1 and none work i still get that same error message?